# ngclass not working with dynamically created components

Tags: angular

I have some components that I create using createComponent. While some components work correctly some don't have proper css classes. I'm using a function and [ngClass] to set the classes but they just aren't there when I inspect the component in dom.

```
constructor (private injector: EnvironmentInjector) {};
const compRef = createComponent(RadioButtonComponent, { environmentInjector: this.injector});
document.body.appendChild(compRef.location.nativeElement);
```

Radio button has code
radio.component.html

```html
<div [ngClass]="classes">
...
</div>
```

radio.component.ts

```
public get classes(): string[] {
let cls: string[] = [];
cls.push('some-class-name');
return cls;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your classes are nor rendered because, you inject your component in the dom but not in the Angular dom. So, I think Angular do not know about your created component and does not trigger get classes().

Instead of using `document.body.appendChild`, use [Renderer2][1] and call his appendChild method.

```
constructor(
    private renderer2: Renderer2,
    private injector: EnvironmentInjector
    ) {}
...
const compRef = createComponent(RadioButtonComponent, { environmentInjector: this.injector});
this.renderer2.appendChild(THE_PARENT_ELEMENT, compRef.location.nativeElement);
```

THE_PARENT_ELEMENT is like elementRef.nativeElement.

Comment: Yea I had tried this. Still gives the same result.

Answer (score 0):

In order for angular to run change detection on your created component you have to attach it to the application as explained [here](https://angular.io/api/core/createComponent#usage-notes) in the docs.

In your case you could probably inject the ApplicationRef in your constructor and use it like this:

```
    constructor (private injector: EnvironmentInjector, private applicationRef: ApplicationRef) {};
    
    const compRef = createComponent(RadioButtonComponent, { environmentInjector: this.injector});
    applicationRef.attachView(compRef.hostView); // this line was added

    document.body.appendChild(compRef.location.nativeElement);
```